# Prove $AB=BA$ for all n x n matrices $B$ if and only if $A=\lambda I_n$ for some real number $\lambda$

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-writing, proof-explanation

[image]

Trying to prove this but I'm stuck. I'm assuming A $\neq$ B.

$$
(AB)_{i,j}=\sum^{n}_{k=1}a_{i,k}b_{k,j}
$$
$$
(BA)_{i,j}=\sum^{n}_{k=1}a_{k,j}b_{i,k}
$$
So we need
$$
(AB)_{i,j} = (BA)_{i,j}
$$
$$
\sum^{n}_{k=1}a_{i,k}b_{k,j} = \sum^{n}_{k=1}a_{k,j}b_{i,k}
$$

If you write out the first few terms
$$
a_{i,1}b_{1,j}+a_{i,2}b_{2,j}+a_{i,3}b_{3,j}+\cdots+a_{i,n}b_{n,j} = a_{1,j}b_{i,1}+a_{2,j}b_{i,2}+a_{3,j}b_{i,2}+\cdots+a_{n,j}b_{i,n}
$$

and I don't know quite how to move forward. You can notice that if you choose some position in $AB$( or $BA$) say $(AB)_{2,3}$ then in the last equation the two $b_{2,3}$ terms are paired with $a_{2,2}$ and $a_{3,3}$ (which we are trying to show must be 1 as we want to show A is the identity matrix) but I don't know how to get there.

Thanks for any help or hints!

Comment: Hint: Try $B=\delta_{i,j}$, meaning only has value of $1$ at the $i,j$ entry and $0$ elsewhere. You can then repeat this process with different $i$ and $j$.